# How can i fix image loading issue in react native

Tags: react-native

Image component does not load this source in IOS :

...

```
<Image
        accessible
        source={{
          uri: "https://logo.clearbit.com/uoregon.edu",
        }}
        style={style || styles.logo}
        onError={(e) => {
          console.log(e);
          setError1(false);
          setError2(true);
        }}
      />
```

...

you can open the source in the browser and see its not broken, but react native cant load it

Comment: What does your `style` or `styles.logo` look like?

Comment: its ok, if i change the source with another image it works. but it doesnt work with this link

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `resizeMode` in image  `style` like this :

```
 style={
      {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
      }
```

if not work , change `resizeMode` to   `resizeMode: 'stretch'` or  `resizeMode: 'cover'`